# (Python) Closing pygame.display in a Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, pygame

I am trying to create a Thread that will continuously run in the background of my program and check whether or not the user has pressed the X button in the top right of the window, and then quit the program if they do press it. This way, no matter what is happening, the user may close the program at any point.

I am new to how Threads work so please bear with me. Here's a simplified version of my code that doesn't work:

```
from threading import Thread
import pygame, sys

def checkForQuit():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        pygame.time.wait(100) # 100ms

if __name__ == "__main__":
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
    quitThread = Thread(target = checkForQuit)
    quitThread.start()
```

The problem with my code right now is that when I run it, the program cannot tell whether or not the close button was pressed or not, and the window hangs until it crashes. I'm not sure if there is an easier way to accomplish my task.

I've tried searching for a question similar but I also don't really know what I'm looking for. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: I think this is a XY problem. Why checking for the QUIT event on another thread? By the way, `pygame.event.get()` *has* to be called on the main thread, otherwise it will not work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you close pygame this way. There should not be a thread needed for it. Since pygame events in the pygame loop are always checked, the pygame.QUIT event will always execute when a user closes it's window.

```
import pygame, sys

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If you want to close it with a thread you can try it like this.

```
import threading
import pygame
import sys

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
    global running
    running = True

    def programCheck():
        while True:
            if not running:
                sys.exit(0)
    t = threading.Thread(target=programCheck)
    t.start()

    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                running = False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```